Using PHP GoogleAds api connection DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED, how to fix
I am trying to connect GoogleAds Api using php for fetching campaign names & cost. Here is below my response of the call:
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.ads.googleads.v14.errors.GoogleAdsFailure",
"errors": [
                    {
                        "errorCode": {
                            "authorizationError": "DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED"
                        },
                        "message": "The developer token is only approved for use with test accounts. To access non-test accounts, apply for Basic or Standard access."
                    }
                ],

Try to get GoogleAds campaign name using customers id.

Your dev token is not approved. It needs to be approved to query a live account.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/common-errors
Apply to have your developer token upgraded to Standard or Basic access. https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/dev-token#step-2

Yes, I have submit for Basic access. Still waiting for feedback from GoogleAds API compliance team.

@Md.KhurshedAlamNayem That's the answertto your question. If you're still waiting for access, that means you have no access.

Yes, you are right, I just get basic access with developer token from GoogleAds API compliance team.
